# Abort trap when reading integer array from binary file in C

Tags: c, binaryfiles

I have 2 files. One for writing to a binary file, and one for reading. For now, I am just trying to write and read an integer array to and from basic binary file. It seems like my code is successful, up until I experience an abort trap 6 after my desired outcome is printed.

I have looked into this issue and what seems to be happening is that I am trying to access memory that I do not have permission to access. I have tried increasing the size of my arrays to fix this issue, however, that does not seem to work. Here are my 2 files.

Writing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){

FILE *fp;
int num[4] = {4,2,3,7};


fp = fopen("tst.bin", "wb+");
fwrite(&num, sizeof(int) * 4, 4, fp);

fclose(fp);

return 0;
}
```

Reading

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

FILE *fp;
int val[4] = {0};
int i;

fp = fopen("tst.bin", "rb");

fread(&val, sizeof(int) * 4, 4, fp);

fclose(fp);

printf("The value is: \n");

for(i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
    printf("%d ", val[i]);
}
printf("\n");

return 0;
}
```

My outcome:

```
The value is: 
4 2 3 7 
Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fwrite(&num, sizeof(int) * 4, 4, fp);

fread(num, sizeof(int) * 4, 1, fp);
```

No! You want

```
fwrite(&val, sizeof(int) * 4, 1, fp);

fread(val, sizeof(int) * 4, 1, fp);
```

You have 1 array of four ints, not 4 of them. Also, taking the address of the array like that is not idiomatic. Just omit the &.

Comment: `fwrite(num, sizeof(int), 4, fp)` might be even better, as it matches the documentation for which argument is the size of each element, and which is the number of elements.  It's just cosmetic, though.

Comment: Does C actually know to read 4 numbers from the file? How does it know when one number ends and the next one starts?

Comment: @smac89: `sizeof(int)` does the trick. If he were doing something even slightly more exotic I'd also correct the size to the size of the array itself.